# Variable in other function has always value zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have problem with one variable.

```
protected void godziny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id_filmu = Request["id"];
        var data = Request["data"];
        var godzina = TimeSpan.Parse(hidden2.Value);
        var query = from h in bazaDC.seanses
                    where h.godzina == godzina && h.id_filmu == int.Parse(id_filmu) && h.data == DateTime.Parse(data)
                    select h;

        foreach (var a in query)
        {
            Session["id_seansu"] = a.id_seansu;
        }
    }
```

id_seansu is declared outside function, just in partial class. I have to get that variable in another function:

```
protected void rezerwujButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dzisiejszaData = DateTime.Today;
        TimeSpan godzinaRezerwacji = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        DateTime dataZarezerwowania;
        TimeSpan czasZarezerwowania;
        var query = from wszystkieRezerwacje in bazaDC.rezerwacjes
                    select wszystkieRezerwacje;



        foreach(var i in query)
        {
            if(i.data_rezerwacji.HasValue && i.czas_rezerwacji.HasValue)
            {
                dataZarezerwowania = i.data_rezerwacji.Value;
                czasZarezerwowania = i.czas_rezerwacji.Value;
            }
        }


        rezerwacje nowaRezerwacja = new rezerwacje();
        if (Session["id_seansu"] != null)
         {
             Response.Write(Session["id_seansu"]);
         };

        /*nowaRezerwacja.imie_klienta = imieTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.nazwisko_klienta = nazwiskoTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.email_klienta = emailTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.nrtel_klienta = nrKomTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.numer_miejsca = Hidden1.Value;
        nowaRezerwacja.data_rezerwacji = dzisiejszaData;
        nowaRezerwacja.czas_rezerwacji = godzinaRezerwacji;
        nowaRezerwacja.id_seansu = id_seansu;



        bazaDC.rezerwacjes.InsertOnSubmit(nowaRezerwacja);
        bazaDC.SubmitChanges();*/
    }
```

But when I wanna write that variable by Response.Write("id_seansu") in rezerwujButton_Click It is always "0".
But when I wanna write it in godziny_Click It have correct value.
Why variable is getting 0 value in another function?

Comment: Because both methods are not called within the same request/response cycle. You'd need to store that value in the "session", or some other persistent state manager

Comment: Ok I got it but It's still not working. In function godziny_Click I have correct value but when I try to write Session["id_seansu"] in rezerwujButton_Click It is always null...

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the first click, the page will post back and hence the value of the variable get reset, to Persist Variable on Postback you have to use either session or ViewState, if the you want this variable in other pages then you can go ahead with session if it is specifically for this page then you have to opt ViewState. You can assign like this:

```
 ViewState.Add("id_seansu","some value");
```

And get value like this:

```
if (ViewState["id_seansu"] != null)
{
   var id_seansu = ViewState["id_seansu"];
}
```

Comment: When I use it I got error exception something like that:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in rezerwacja_kino.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Which means you may access the value before assign something to it, Take a look into the updates

Comment: The same with viewstate like a session, in another function than godziny_Click viewstate["id_seansu"]; is always null, why?:(